# Can TrueCrypt automatically dismount a volume when laptop shuts down?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, encryption, truecrypt, disk-encryption

I created an encrypted volume in a partition in my laptop. But I'm worried to forget to unmount it when I close the laptop (which may put it in standby or hibernate) and somebody be able to hack Windows to login in and find the partition mounted.

TrueCrypt automatically dismounts its volumes when Windows is shutting down, and when a PC is in standby/hybernate we can remove a pendrive without corrupting it. But I tested closing the laptop and opening it and the encrypted partition was still available.

Is it possible to configure TrueCrypt to unmount volumes when I close the laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your options and set the auto dismount settings.   I believe 'Enter Power Saving' mode will do the trick.

http://www.truecrypt.org/screenshots6

Comment: It worked tnx! When I bring laptop back from sleep, volumes are unmounted and WinExplorer is closed. I couldn't test it with a file opened, but I suppose that Windows forces closing all opened streams. An app tried to open a file it knows is there and it failed with expection saying "error while trying to write to file, the device is not ready"